# Modified WaveletImagePlot

Tags: wavelet-analysis

When performing Wavelet Transform

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[img, HaarWavelet[], 2]
WaveletImagePlot[dwd]
```

I get the plot:

[image: Image plot]

But I want to subdivide image 4 instead of image 1 -- any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by subdivide ? Actually performing DWT on the `{3}` coefficient or just scrambling the `WaveletImagePlot` ?

Comment: Performing DWT on {3}

Comment: `DiscreteWaveletPacketTransform`